# let nginx cache files depending on filename only (instead of full path)

Tags: caching, nginx

This question is about caching of nginx only, not about the cache headers and browser cache.

I am operating an application that displays details of items on URLs of the form

```
http://my-server/details/<id>/
```

where *id* is a unique identifier of the item. While the resulting HTML page is auto-generated and unique to the item, the page relatively includes other JavaScript and CSS files. Those files are static and do **not** depend on the item id. the application is very slow and I want nginx to cache whatever is possible.

nginx acts as a reverse proxy. Is it possible to set the [proxy_cache_key](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_key) property for all .js and .css subrequests to the filename only (omitting the id from the url)?

Example: Accessing *http://my-server.tld/details/abc/style.css* first and *http://my-server.tld/details/def/style.css* afterwards should therefore result in a cache hit. But accessing *http://my-server.tld/details/abc/* and *http://my-server/details/def/* afterwards should not (generated HTML depends on id).

This is what I am thinking of as base configuration

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my-server.tld;

  location / {
    # root, doesn't matter
  }

  location /details {
    # request to non-asset, cache as usual
  }

  location ~ ^/details/[a-z0-9]+/[a-z0-9]+\.(js|css)$ {
    # request to static asset, use filename only as cache key
  }
}
```

Comment: That you mean "application is very slow"? Request of HTML are slow, or css requests are slow too? If css requests slow - why? Is it generated by application on the fly, or it's static file?

Comment: @Terra the application runs on an underdimensioned vm and legacy application server (and I may not change that). each request is slow (latency and transmission speed), even static resources like css.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can define a key for caching. Here is an example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-server.tld;

    location / {
        # root, doesn't matter
    }

    location /details {
        # request to non-asset, cache as usual
    }
    location ~ ^/details/[a-z0-9]+/(?<cache_filename>[a-z0-9]+\.(js|css))$ {
        proxy_cache_key "/details/$cache_filename";            

        # Other configurations
        # <...>
    }
}
```